# Add to a list records from table 1 that has ID the same as records from table 2

Tags: c#, linq, orm, entity-framework-5

I have been trying to get this one to work, but so far I couldn't.
What happen is I have 2 tables Table1 and Table2, I got the records from Table2 to list

```
List<Table2Name> listTbl2 = (from o in context.Table2 select o).ToList();
List<Table1Name> listTbl1 = new List<Table1Name>();
```

In listTbl2, there is a column ID, Table1 also has same col ID...
Now I want to get records from Table1 that has matching column ID with the listTbl2, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

NoobieCoder,

try this.

```
var results = (from t1 in context.Table1
              join t2 in listTbl2 on t1.ID equals t2.ID 
              select t1).Distinct();
```

Comment: I edited my answer to use Table1 instead of listTbl1.

Comment: doesn't work. I just double check and found out you cant join a query with a local list in C#. Gotta find another way

Comment: @NoobieCoder, my apologies I was using LinqPad to test with. i'll get you how to do this via c#.